# Pyspark spark.read.csv().collect() return an empty list

Tags: python, list, pyspark, collect

I've been trying to use `df.collect()` method to see the content of my cells in pyspark 3.1.2
but it keeps returning an empty list :  `etp.collect() []`
Even though `etp.show()` is giving me results

The code i'm using :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName('Read_csv')\
    .getOrCreate()

etp= spark.read.options(header=True)\
.options(delimiter=';')\
.options(inferschema='true')\
.csv("mypath\etp.csv")

etp.collect()
```

I've tried changing the delimiter, same problem/

My goal is to iterate on the content of the cell based of the row number, but if i cant access the content it's no use.
Any ideas of things i could try or change ?

Thanks in advance

Edit : I'm using jupyter notebook
Edit 2 : I've tried other operations such as withColumn... and they seem to work. Select().show() also. It feels like .collect() has been changed
but i cant find the info

Comment: To confirm the output seen after executing cell containing `etp.collect()` is `[]`?

Comment: hey !
Yes, exactly.

Comment: Can you confirm if `etp.count()` returns a value

Comment: yes, it does return 14

Answer (score 0):

Using the following Dataframe as an example, which has a distinct `ROW_ID` column

```
+------+----+---+
|ROW_ID|NAME|AGE|
+------+----+---+
|     1|John| 50|
|     2|Anna| 32|
|     3|Josh| 41|
|     4|Paul| 98|
+------+----+---+
```

You can access the `name` cell of the 3rd row with the following

```
df.where(df["ROW_ID"] == 3).collect()[0]["NAME"]
```

Feel free to recreate this example with the following code

```
from pyspark.sql import types

data = [ 
        [1, "John", 50],
        [2, "Anna", 32],
        [3, "Josh", 41],
        [4, "Paul", 98],
        ]

arr_schema = (types.StructType([
        types.StructField('ROW_ID', types.IntegerType()),
        types.StructField('NAME', types.StringType()),
        types.StructField('AGE', types.IntegerType()),
        ]))

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=arr_schema)

df.where(df["ROW_ID"] == 3).collect()[0]["NAME"]
```

Comment: If you provide a sample of data from df.show(), I will tailor my answer to the data you are working with

Comment: Hey Bredan, thank you for the answer. I'm suspecting that the problem is coming from my installation of anaconda, other packages have been acting pretty strange. I'm reinstalling everything towmorrow in a virtual env and i'll try again, including your solution. I'll post here for a heads up.
Regards

Comment: Hey, after reinstalling everything it now works as intended. I dont really now what caused the problem, but it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected a bad installation. So i uninstalled anaconda and then created a virtual env where i installed only the packages i needed and it worked.